# Docker image building error based on webProfile7 using Microclimate

Tags: docker, microclimate

I remember this worked well at least 4 weeks ago.

Since 2 weeks ago, webProfile7 docker image has been updated several times.

Anyway, I try to build the project of MicroProfile framework, but I meet the failure at the step for building the container image.

According to my log file, `mkdir -p /root/java` command failed with below error message given

> cannot create directory '/root': Permission denied

This command is one of Dockerfile-build.

Anybody helps me ?

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible dockerfile to your question.

Comment: Share the Dockerfile here to check

Comment: Temporarily, I changed user to root. And it looks like working well. I opened this issue at the below.  https://github.com/microclimate-dev2ops/microclimate-dev2ops.github.io/issues/27#issue-374615864  I will follow this issue there.   Thanks for being interested in my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the WebSphere Liberty docker container, and we are actively pursuing a fix in Microclimate for this.

In the meanwhile, adding "USER root" to the project's Dockerfile-build in Microclimate will resolve the issue.